# Python test succeed on Linux but fail on windows

Tags: python, django, linux, windows, testing

I'm currently working on a project where my python tests are actually succeeding when they are running on a Linux environment, but they fail when they are running in a Windows environment.
And what is really weird is that the tests are failing randomly on Windows(sometimes, 4 tests are failing, sometimes it's 6...).
I have the feeling that maybe the setUp method doesn't execute the same way in Linux and in Windows.

Does anyone know if there is a difference between python test run on windows or on linux.
Thank you.

Comment: There are many differences. It could be default file encoding, paths, permissions,  or who knows what else. Without an error message it is hard to say more.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.